# Whats the best option to save a image file agains a customer in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, file-upload

I'm developing a Magento module, which allows customers to upload image files at the product page for the selected product. This can be done as a guest or a logged in customer. What would be the best way to store these uploaded files against a guest customer and for a logged in customer?

N.B : This is before saving images against the customer order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach that I took as a solution to this problem, is to create a folder in Magneto Media folder and name it with visitor_id. This is valid for either registered or guest users.

```
$session      = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$custdir_name = $session['visitor_data']['customer_id'];
$image_path   = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/'.$custdir_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Custom options feature of magento.

Add file type custom options for product and customer can able to upload image on product page.

And uploaded image is saved with order so you can able to see image on order view page .

Comment: Yep, thats one option, unfortunately there are some complications around it that I cannot use this option. Because there are different design of the same product, some may not have to have a image upload.

Comment: If you are using different design for same product then I think you are using different phtml file too for product view page so you can put condition based on that for display of custom options.